# Deleted Content?

Tags: discussion, questions

Can anybody else see my deleted questions on Stack Overflow?

It means I have deleted a question or an answer on Stack Overflow will anybody will be able to see it other than me.

Comment: Diamond Moderators can see deleted content of a user, from their profile. That is kept confidential.

Comment: 10k users can see deleted questions and answers, provided that they have the link. Diamond moderators also have the ability to search deleted content.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can anybody else see my deleted questions on Stack Overflow

Yes and no.

Yes so far as in **everyone who has at least 10.000 reputation or is a moderator can see deleted posts**, and that includes yours.

No as in that deleted posts aren't easily searchable, so for instance if I had 10.000 reputation I could not go to your profile and find all deleted posts by you easily.

But if a  10k user came across a question where you had a deleted answer, they could see it, for instance.

Diamond moderators can also see all deleted content, and they can easily search for it.